# How to read matlab datetimes stored in a file using scipy.io.loadmat

Tags: python, matlab, datetime, scipy, mat

I have a -v7 file `myfilename` which I created in matlab.
It contains a nested structure, which contains a UTC timestamp

```
 mydata.sub1.time_utc(1)
ans = 
   31-Jan-2018 09:25:52
    class(s.sub1.time_utc)
ans =
datetime
```

I open the file via python, using scipy

```
matlabcontents=scipy.io.loadmat(fn_full)
```

then I can access all of my struct but not the time_utc
but then I can not see inspecting the object

```
matlabcontents['mydata']['sub1']
```

I can not see the 'time_utc' in the fields.

I also have tried :

```
matlabcontents=scipy.io.loadmat(myfilename ,squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
matlabcontents['mydata'].__dict__['sub1'].__dict__['time_utc']
```

This way I can access `'time_utc'`, but I get the following which is indeed 'opaque' to me

```
MatlabOpaque([ ('', 'MCOS', 'datetime', array([3707764736,          2,          1,          1,          1,
                1], dtype=uint32))], 
      dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])
```

How to access matlab datetimes from python?

Comment: Save them in string format instead. Datetime is a Matlab specific type that is probably not handled in loadmat.

Comment: do you have a one-line for me to do that?

Comment: t = datetime('now'); s = datestr(t);

Comment: An earlier SO question with `MatlabOpaque` objects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913301/matlab-date-string-results-in-java-lang-string-in-python-scipy-io