# Open .mat (matlab data) using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scipy

I tried to import and read .mat file from Python. I have tried two ways but been unsuccessful.

Method 1 (In Python):

```python
import scipy.io as sio    
mat = sio.loadmat('path/tmpPBworkspace.mat')
```

I get a message similar to:

```
{'None': MatlabOpaque([ (b'rateQualityOutTrim', b'MCOS', b'dataset', array([[3707764736],
        [         2],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
              dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]),
 '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Thu May 10 07:11:52 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0'}
```

I am not sure what went wrong there? I was hoping to see a data frame. Also to add, in Method 1, I have saved the .mat in a version compatible with SciPy.

In Matlab:

```matlab
save('path/tmpPBworkspace.mat','rateQualityOutTrim','-v7')
```

Also tried the other way:

Method 2: h5py

In Matlab:

```matlab
save('path/tmpPBworkspaceH5.mat','rateQualityOutTrim','-v7.3')
```

In Python:

```python
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('/GAAR/ustr/projects/PBF/tmpPBworkspaceH5.mat','r')
data = f.get('rateQualityOutTrim/date')
data = np.array(data)
```

I get

```
f
Out[154]: <HDF5 file "tmpPBworkspaceH5.mat" (mode r)>

data
array(None, dtype=object)
```

The array is empty. Not sure how I can access the data here as well.

Comment: The Opaque item is a matlab class object that it can't turn into a numpy array.

Comment: thanks hpaulj   any idea on how I can read .mat ?

Comment: what is the matlab object?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I don't about datasets in MATLAB or whether they are compatible with `pandas`.  But to load variables with `loadmat`, you have to write matrices, cells, or structs.

Comment: When I've looked at H5 files, I'v had systematically search the datagroups and datasets.  `h5dump` may give a quick overview.

Comment: A previous question about a `MatlabOpaque`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913301/matlab-date-string-results-in-java-lang-string-in-python-scipy-io; and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512560/access-mat-file-containing-matlab-classes-in-python

Comment: If you are really in control of Matlab part, don't use any Matlab class objects, rather go with **MATLAB arrays, cells, and struct** (as these can be turned into a numpy array). I'm not much familiar with Matlab, but it might be possible to use `struct(your_class_object)` to convert it.

Comment: Another option is to use kind of reverse engineering and parse `__function_workspace__` data (very long array that you can see in your dict after using `scipy.io.loadmat`) - check [this link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/mbauman/9121961). But as you can see, it's not a nice way of working with .mat files.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat) for this:

```
from scipy import io

loaded = io.loadmat('/GAAR/ustr/projects/PBF/tmpPBworkspaceH5.mat')
```

`loaded` will be a dictionary mapping names to arrays.

---

If you're in control of both the Matlab part and the Pandas part, however, it is much easier to use [`csvwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html):

In Matlab:

```
csvwrite('path/tmpPBworkspaceH5.csv','rateQualityOutTrim')
```

In Python:

```
pd.read_csv('tmpPBworkspaceH5.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks Ami Tavory. I did that and I get similar message as before `{'None': MatlabOpaque([ (b'rateQualityOutTrim', b'MCOS', b'dataset', array([[3707764736],
        [         2],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
              dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]),
 '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8),
 '__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: GLNXA64, Created on: Fri May 11 03:33:35 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0'}`

Comment: still not sure how i can extract the data?

Comment: @SBad Got it - this is explained very nicely in [this notebook](https://gist.github.com/mbauman/9121961) - it's in Julia, but you can follow the explanations.

Comment: @SBad Incidentally, looking at your question, it looks like you're in control of the Matlab part as well. In this case, there are much easier options. I edited my answer to include one.

Comment: @SBad It's a long answer, since this format is really not meant to be used for exporting - it's reverse engineered, and you probably don't want to write in it to the first place.

Comment: I have a very large dataset (more than a million rows) and exporting to csv is not optimal and may take a very long time. saving the data as .mat and importing in python may be the best solution i think.

Answer (score 0):

I also would try it with scipy.io.

I have a Matlab "struct" (Auslage_000.mat) that I understand as some sort of nested dictionary. It has several header information and three data channels (vibration data). I also find Spyder (Python Development Environment) helpful as once the data is loaded you can access the data via a variable manager (similar to Matlab).

```python
import scipy.io as sio
    
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('Auslage_000.mat',squeeze_me=True,struct_as_record=False)
```

When I check the output of my variable "mat_contends" I get

```
mat_contents

Out[14]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on 2019-08-14 13:14:56 by TiePie software (www.tiepie.com).',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'tpd': <scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.mat_struct at 0x1ea3441d438>}
```

My actual data is in `tpd`. I can further access the data as follows:

```python
#Access the data via the key 'tpd' and then the attribute 'Data'
# -> Data is a numpy array with 3 channels (ch1, ch2, ch3) / dimensions
Data = mat_contents['tpd'].Data
    
# extract channel1 
    
ch1 = Data[0]
```

I guess you have to dig a little bit as first you have "keys" and the "attributes" in your Matlab file (if it is a struct).