# How to extract Camera calibration parameters from matlab matrix .mat to python numpy arrays?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, camera-calibration

- I have done camera calibration via Matlab 2019a, then I have saved the variable `cameraParams` which turns to be all the camera parameters, but I'm only interested in **Intrinsic matrix**, and **distortion coefficients**.
- How can I extract these two arrays from the `cameraParams.mat` file?[Mat file attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tSCkbVCmH4CAiQJusK0eSnI0yVoYUxvL/view?usp=sharing)
- **clarification:**( the Intrinsic matrix, is 3x3 matrix, and the distortion coefficients, are 4 coefficients in Matlab, 2 for radial, and 2 for tangential distortion)
- I have tried the following code, but I didn't know how to extract the arrays:

```py
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

Mat = sio.loadmat('CameraParams.mat')

for key in Mat :
    print(key, Mat[key])
```

The output is:

```
__header__ b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Feb  2 12:32:06 2021'
__version__ 1.0
__globals__ []
None [(b'cameraParams', b'MCOS', b'cameraParameters', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))]
__function_workspace__ [[ 0  1 73 ...  0  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that MatlabOpaque objects can not be accessed as stated in [mbauman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283663/13934111). The easiest solution is to resave the object in MATLAB as `struct(CameraParams)`.

You can also check [this repo](https://github.com/yusufguleray/CalibrationParameters-Matlab2NumPy) for easy conversion from .mat to numpy.

Answer (score 1):

**You've already figured it out IMO**. Note it's useful to use `type()` and `isinstance()` to see what type of variables you're dealing with. **In my code the numpy arrays are available as `v` under the `if instance()` statement:**

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np

Mat = sio.loadmat('CameraParams.mat')

for k, v in Mat.items():
    print("\n\n", k, type(v), v)
    if isinstance(v, np.ndarray):  # Numpy array?
        print(' --> Numpy array')
```

Output:

```
 __header__ <class 'bytes'> b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Feb  2 12:32:06 2021'


 __version__ <class 'str'> 1.0


 __globals__ <class 'list'> []


 None <class 'scipy.io.matlab.mio5_params.MatlabOpaque'> [(b'cameraParams', b'MCOS', b'cameraParameters', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))]
 --> Numpy array


 __function_workspace__ <class 'numpy.ndarray'> [[ 0  1 73 ...  0  0  0]]
 --> Numpy array
```

**The last 2 items are already numpy arrays**, FYI the `MatlabOpaque` class returns a numpy array:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/matlab/mio5_params.py#L247

**As for the output of `loadmat()` method, it seems some elements can be accessed directed if you know their name**:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.0/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py#L214

```
matstruct_squeezed = sio.loadmat(matstruct_fname, squeeze_me=True)
matstruct_squeezed['teststruct']['complexfield'].item()
array([ 1.41421356+1.41421356j,  2.71828183+2.71828183j,
        3.14159265+3.14159265j])
```

Comment: yes indeed they are `numpy` array, my issue here is that: how to get the correct indices of my parameters(9 for intrinsic matrix, and 4,5,8 maybe 12 for the distortion)  from the last `numpy` array in your answer.

Comment: The best is to look at the source to see how the outpout of `loadmat()` is constructued, the source contains some examples where values are accessed directly by name, see update at the bottom of my answer

Answer (score 1):

In an Ipython session:

```
In [385]: data = loadmat('../Downloads/CameraParams.mat')
```

`data` is a `dict`, from which we can use keys to view variables from the file:

```
In [386]: data
Out[386]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Tue Feb  2 12:32:06 2021',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'None': MatlabOpaque([(b'cameraParams', b'MCOS', b'cameraParameters', array([[3707764736],
        [         2],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1],
        [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
              dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')]),
 '__function_workspace__': array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

`MatlabOpaque` denotes some sort of MATLAB object or class that can't be totally converted to a Python/numpy.  But here it contains a structured array:

```
In [387]: data['None']
Out[387]: 
MatlabOpaque([(b'cameraParams', b'MCOS', b'cameraParameters', array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32))],
             dtype=[('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])
In [388]: data['None'].dtype
Out[388]: dtype([('s0', 'O'), ('s1', 'O'), ('s2', 'O'), ('arr', 'O')])
```

From which we can select fields:

```
In [389]: data['None']['s0']
Out[389]: MatlabOpaque([b'cameraParams'], dtype=object)

In [390]: data['None']['arr']
Out[390]: 
MatlabOpaque([array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32)], dtype=object)
```

And use `item` to pull the array out of the object dtype wrapper:

```
In [391]: data['None']['arr'].item()
Out[391]: 
array([[3707764736],
       [         2],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1],
       [         1]], dtype=uint32)
```

That is a (6,1) array.

```
In [392]: data['__function_workspace__']
Out[392]: array([[ 0,  1, 73, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=uint8)
In [393]: data['__function_workspace__'].shape
Out[393]: (1, 33848)
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer, my confusion is that: how to extract the intrinsic parameters (3x3) matrix = 9 elements, and distortion which can be 4,5,8,12 elements, from the last result `33848`in your answer, I'm just confused how to find their correct indices.

Comment: `MatlabOpaque` means `loadmat` can't look inside it - it's a 'opaque', presumably some sort of MATLAB class or function that cannot be translated into Python/numpy.  The best you can do is go back to the MATLAB source, and write these parameters as separate variables.